# Is there a way to deploy Django with other web applications?

Tags: python, django, debian, web-deployment

I'm starting a new personal server in a VPS (debian). I am doing the mainpage with django. I will like to add to this server/site other external apps (such as GitLab CE, [Veloren](https://veloren.net/) , FluxRSS and Wallabag).

The idea is to centralize everything through django. To have something like :

- Blog : `webpage.com`
- GitLab : `gitlab.webpage.com`

Nevertheless, I cannot seem to find any tutorials or information to do this. I think there is something related to `nginx` and reverse proxy, but still cant find good information.
I know the question is very broad but I'm out of resources and do not know where to search...

I've been searching through the web (including stackoverflow) and can't seem to find what I'm looking for, so even if it is just keyword recommendations or links to possible solutions/implementations I'll be extremely happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for virtual hosts

https://linuxiac.com/nginx-virtual-host/

Comment: Thanks ! If it is what I search i'll give you the answer points :)